# Excel - Check if two values exist together in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to be able to check if user in `B2` has access to applications in `A3:A6`.

I have a list of all users and what they have access too, how will I be able to match and compare both lists and place a Yes or No in the table?

Please see the example from the screenshot below:

[image: Example]

I've had a look at `VLookups` etc but any help wouldn't go a miss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$1&$A2,$H$2:$H$15&$G$2:$G$15,0)),"Y","N")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfectly - Thanks!

Comment: @Bewing please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.